# example of how do include one or more than one procedure(s) in one oracle script execute within the script - see example below

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

**Question: Oracle Script - how do include one or more than one procedure(s) in one single oracle script**

```
set pagesize 1000
set linesize 220
set trimspool on
set tab offset numwidth 10

procedure test01
as
begin


end test01;

procedure test02
as
begin


end test02;

execute test01;
execute test02;
```

Comment: Are you answering your own question?

Comment: Looks like you're just missing **CREATE** procedure; or did we not understand the question?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you're looking for but this does work:

script content:

```
set pagesize 1000
set linesize 220
set trimspool on
set tab offset numwidth 10
set serveroutput on

create procedure test01
as
begin
  dbms_output.put_line('this is test01');
end test01;
/

create procedure test02
as
begin
  dbms_output.put_line('this is test02');
end test02;
/



execute test01;
execute test02;
```

running the script:

```
koen 19c>@/tmp/script

Procedure TEST01 compiled


Procedure TEST02 compiled

this is test01


PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

this is test02


PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

Comment: You will get errors with the `CREATE PROCEDURE` statements if you try to run the script a second time. (The `CREATE PROCEDURE` statements should be run once and not included in the script.)

Comment: @MTO I realize that. Just took over the syntax of OP - should have mentioned the limitations.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to define a non-stored procedure then define it in the `DECLARE` section of a PL/SQL block and call it in the `BEGIN` section of the PL/SQL block:

```sql
set pagesize 1000
set linesize 220
set trimspool on
set tab offset numwidth 10

DECLARE
  procedure test01
  as
  begin
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('test01');
  end test01;

  procedure test02
  as
  begin
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('test02');
  end test02;
BEGIN
  test01;
  test02;
END;
/
```

Which outputs:

> ```
> test01
> test02
> ```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/tQY-PkR1)

If you want to define a stored procedure then use `CREATE PROCEDURE` to create the procedure once (outside your script):

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE test01
as
begin
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('test01');
end test01;
/

CREATE PROCEDURE test02
as
begin
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('test02');
end test02;
/
```

and then only call the procedure from your script:

```sql
set pagesize 1000
set linesize 220
set trimspool on
set tab offset numwidth 10
set serveroutput on

execute test01;
execute test02;
```